# How to install quicktime player?

Tags: debian

Is there any way to install quicktime Player in Debian?
If yes, then how?
I tried installing with command

```
sudo apt-get install quicktime
```

But get error package not found.

Comment: this may help- http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fforums.debian.net%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D6%26t%3D32737&ei=2YEDU_37BMb4yAHZwIDwCg&usg=AFQjCNFmhimAarUThn-hNRWaI7mfPc7JHg&sig2=eL8cbDRI1bSsrfVSBuw_IA&bvm=bv.61535280,d.aWc

Answer (score 0):

checkout https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages whenever you have a question of whether something is available on debian.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to find a particular package that you want to install, try to search for it first to see if it exists. If you had used aptitude you would have found quicktime-utils.

```
$ aptitude search quicktime
    p   libquicktime-dev                - library for reading and writing Quicktime 
    p   libquicktime-doc                - library for reading and writing Quicktime 
    p   libquicktime2                   - library for reading and writing Quicktime 
    p   quicktime-utils                 - library for reading and writing Quicktime 
    p   quicktime-x11utils              - library for reading and writing Quicktime
```